# Ruby set with custom class

Tags: ruby, set

I'm trying to correctly implement some custom classes in order to use them in a set. Custom class B contains an array instance variable that holds objects of class A. Here's a MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'set'

class A
  attr_reader :a

  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def hash
    @a.hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    @a == other.a
  end
end

class B
  attr_reader :instances

  def initialize
    @instances = Array.new
  end

  def add(i)
    @instances.push(i)
  end

  def hash
    @instances.hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    @instances == other.instances
    #@instances.eql?(other.instances)
  end
end

s = Set.new

b1 = B.new
b1.add(A.new(4))
b1.add(A.new(5))

b2 = B.new
b2.add(A.new(4))
b2.add(A.new(5))

s.add(b1)
s.add(b1)
s.add(b2)
puts s.size
```

The output is `2`, expected is `1` since `b1` and `b2` are objects constructed with the same values.

If I use `eql?` instead of `==` in the implementation of `eql?` in class B, then the output is correct. According to the definition of `==` in the [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3D-3D), shouldn't the use of `==` be correct here?  Where is my error in understanding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR it's because:

- `Array#==` compares elements via `==`
- `Array#eql?` compares elements via `eql?`

---

> According to the definition of `==` in the ruby docs, shouldn't the use of `==` be correct here?

If you compare the arrays via [`Array#==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-3D-3D) the corresponding items will also be compared via `==`: (emphasis added)

> Two arrays are equal if they contain the same number of elements and if each element is equal to (**according to Object#==**)

Example:

```
[A.new(4)] == [A.new(4)]
#=> false
```

it fails because the elements are not equal according to `==`:

```
A.new(4) == A.new(4)
#=> false
```

> If I use `eql?` instead of `==` in the implementation of `eql?` in class `B`, then the output is correct.

[`Array#eql?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-eql-3F) works, because it compares corresponding items via `eql?`: (emphasis added)

> Returns `true` if self and other are the same object, or are both arrays with the same content (**according to Object#eql?**).

Example:

```
[A.new(4)].eql? [A.new(4)]
#=> true
```

because of:

```
A.new(4).eql? A.new(4)
#=> true
```

In order to get `==` working, you have to implement `A#==`:

```
class A
  # ...
  def eql?(other)
    @a == other.a
  end
  alias_method :==, :eql?
end

A.new(4) == A.new(4)     #=> true
[A.new(4)] == [A.new(4)] #=> true
```

Comment: And I had not checked that the OP had an implementation of `eql?`. Even.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, that all makes perfect sense, thank you! One more thing, though: this works out fine in irb, but if I add the method alias to my original script in class A and B (without any other change, seems to be the only thing necessary according to your explanation), I still get `2` as a result...